# Map operator < conditions - invalid comparator

Tags: c++, string, stl, operator-overloading

I need to check if two substrings are equal while inserting to a map. Here is the code:

```
class substring {
public:

    substring(string* str, int offset, int length) : str(str), offset(offset), length(length) {  }


    bool operator < (const substring& val) const {

        if (str->compare(offset, length, *val.str, val.offset, val.length) == 0) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    int offset, length;
    string* str;

};
```

This class above is a 'key' in my map. **Lengths of both substrings are always same.** Some of the conditions are wrong, cause it's still yelling 'invalid comparator'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your if statement in comparation function code is convoluted way to say:

```
return str->compare(offset, length, *val.str, val.offset, val.length) != 0;
```

which is incorrect for comparison function that `std::map` requires. Remember you are implementing less than operator, not equivalence. If you want your substring to be sorted in ascending order use this:

```
return str->compare(offset, length, *val.str, val.offset, val.length) < 0;
```

I would recommend using const reference to `std::string` in you `substring` class - that will reflect the fact you do not accept `nullptr` as pointer and show intent that you do not want to change original string through this class  and make your code cleaner.

Comment: Your recommendation would also make the class non assignable.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley agree, but if it's intended use is only as a key for map then it should be fine. Or at least ctor parameter should be a ref, implementation can be with a pointer.